# How to create table from existing 2 table with default value and datatype in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create new table from existing 2 table selected column, with new column contain 99999999 which datatype must be number like dummy value.

I tried below code

```
 CREATE TABLE NewTbl1 as 
 SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, '99999999' as dummycol
 FROM tbl1 a JOINtbl2 b 
  ON a.col1 = b.colNum AND a.col2 = b.colnum1;
```

this query run properly but 'dummycol' datatype would be char type. I want it as number. If I remove single quotes using only `99999999` then the table is created but when I am going to open it, give me error that Conversion from "DBNULL" to "integer" is not valid.
I tried below code also to cast column as

```
Cast(99999999 AS NUMBER) AS dummycol
```

But still facing same error:

> Conversion from "DBNULL" to "integer" is not valid.

when open table.

Comment: What does "when I am going to open it" mean?  It sounds like whatever tool/ framework/ GUI you are using to "open" the table has a problem with columns that are declared as `number` which would allow 38 digits.  Perhaps you want a `number(8,0)`

Comment: @JustinCave- open it mens  when I expand column. But thanks number(8,0) works perfectly.

Comment: @JustinCave- If I want to give it as NOT NULL also then how to do?

Comment: You can't.  You could do a separate `alter` to add a `not null` constraint.  I'd suggest that you probably want to just do a straight `create table` with the appropriate data types, column names, and constraints and then insert the data later.  Assuming it really makes sense to create the table in the first place.

Comment: The error message comes from your SQL client - which tool are you using to display this? And what exactly does "open the table" mean? And what is the DDL that is generated for the table when you use `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'NEWTBL1') from dual`?